# How to choose the way to get WordPress data?

Tags: wordpress

Studying WordPress, I realized that there are so many ways to 
get data.

For example, to get post ID on single.php at least you can use following 3 ways.

**-1. Use function get_the_ID**

```php
$my_id1 = get_the_ID();
```

**-2. Use Global Variable $post**

```php
$my_id2 = $post->ID;
```

**-3. Use function get_post and its Object**

```php
$my_id3 = get_post();
$my_id3 = $my_id3->ID;
```

I don't know what would be better practice.
Is there any reason to pick one over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;**

If there's a helper function available that returns the data you need, most of the time you'll want to use that function instead of accessing objects' properties/methods directly to reduce the chance of bugs/errors in the future.

---

Generally speaking, either way should be fine as it's not very likely that WordPress will introduce drastic changes to its existing objects, classes & APIs so you can expect that -following the examples from your question- the `$post` object will surely have an `ID` attribute assigned to it that you can use in your code.

With that being said, using helper functions is a sure way to get the data you expect in the format you expect it to be whether WordPress internally makes changes to its classes/objects/APIs or not.

Here's an extreme example:

Imagine that someone at WordPress was feeling bored and decided to rename the `ID` attribute of the `$post` object to `item_ID`. If you're using the `get_the_ID()` function in your code, you know for sure that no matter what that function will return an integer and everything will be fine because that function internally must surely have been updated by the WordPress team so it returns the value of `item_ID` instead of `ID`.

This, on the other hand:

```
$my_id2 = $post->ID; // The ID attribute no longer exists, now it's called item_ID!
```

... will throw an error as `ID` no longer exists in this scenario, breaking your code (remember, this is an extreme example that assumes that the `ID` attribute was renamed to `item_ID`.)

Again, this is an unlikely scenario. Frameworks as big as WordPress usually avoid introducing breaking changes like this to existing APIs/functions/objects unless there's a **very** good reason to do so, and in such scenario they usually give a heads-up to us developers so we can adjust our code accordingly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good answer and it's all clear now.
I'll try to pick helper functions first.
Thank you so much and have a good rest of the day!